# What would the bandwidth be while transferring from a machine with a 2.5 Gbps NIC to a machine with a 10 Gbps NIC?

Tags: network, bandwidth

I have two machines connected via a managed network switch capable of supporting 10 Gbps bandwidth.

What would the bandwidth be if I transfer data from machine 1 with a 2.5 Gbps network card to machine 2 with a 10 Gbps network card?

Comment: TCP throughput also depends on the “window size” and round trip time. So even if you have continuous 10gbit/sec bandwidth, your transfers will not achieve that bandwidth if you have a significant round-trip time.  Some specialized file transfer application use UDP or adjust the TCP window to improve the throughput.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've likely heard of the expression "a chain is only as strong as its weakest link".

The same concept is true of most things, network connectivity and performance not withstanding.  Your throughput will only be as fast as the slowest member.  So, if you have one side that is only capable of 2.5Gbps and another that is capable of 10Gbps, you will be limited to 2.5Gbps.  Realistically, your transfer rate may not ever reach even that.